# Embed Tomcat-7 to run only in https

Tags: java, tomcat7

I want to run embedded tomcat that uses only HTTPS (8443). I do not want 8080 port to be used at all.
Any idea about ?

```
    Connector httpsConnector = new Connector();
    httpsConnector.setPort(httpsPort);
    httpsConnector.setSecure(true);
    httpsConnector.setScheme("https");
    httpsConnector.setAttribute("keystoreFile", appBase + "/.keystore");
    httpsConnector.setAttribute("clientAuth", "false");
    httpsConnector.setAttribute("sslProtocol", "TLS");
    httpsConnector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled", true);

    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.getService().addConnector(httpsConnector);
    tomcat.setPort(8080);
    Connector defaultConnector = tomcat.getConnector();
    defaultConnector.setRedirectPort(8443);

    tomcat.setBaseDir(".");
    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(appBase);

    StandardServer server = (StandardServer) tomcat.getServer();
    AprLifecycleListener listener = new AprLifecycleListener();
    server.addLifecycleListener(listener);
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to forbid the 8080 port?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to remove the connector defined in [tomcat-dir]/conf/server.xml which binds it to 8080 and have a separate connector for HTTPS.

Comment: Actually i am embedding tomcat, i don't use server.xml there. Programmatically connector will be added

Comment: How is your tomcat starting up ? Can you provide more details in your question ?

Comment: @Srinivas Not sure I understand completely. what do you clearly mean by **embedding** ? Are you creating a customized server of your own ? Even if you manage to start this **embedded** server, how are deployments/classloading being handled ? Inshort, What is your final goal ?

Comment: I will start/stop tomcat server from a Custom Java Class, where i will mention which web applications need to be deployed. As you can see from the above code Tomcat's DefaultConnector will be http, but i don't want that connector. I will create new HTTPS Connector. So finally i want to run Tomcat in only 8443 port (https)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using the snippet in the question for creating the `httpsConnector` and it worked great! Except I had to add one missing line:

```
httpsConnector.setAttribute("keystorePass", "YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE");
```

Setting that to the password I setup when [creating the keystore](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Installing_a_Certificate_from_a_Certificate_Authority) with `keytool` did the trick.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get the defaultConnector from the Tomcat instance and set it up for https. In this way there is no other connector:

```
    Connector defaultConnector = tomcat.getConnector();
    defaultConnector.setPort(8443);
    defaultConnector.setSecure(true);
    defaultConnector.setScheme("https");
    defaultConnector.setAttribute("keystorePass", "password");
    defaultConnector.setAttribute("keystoreFile", absolutePath + "/keystore.jks");
    defaultConnector.setAttribute("clientAuth",  "false");
    defaultConnector.setAttribute("sslProtocol",  "TLS");
    defaultConnector.setAttribute("SSLEnabled",  true);
```